# Can you prove that all of these "almost polynomials" have some zeros with real part $1/2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Consider the almost polynomial:
$$P(x)=-x+x^* \sum _{k=1}^n x^k+x^{n+1}$$
with the conjugate variable $x^*$ in front of the sum, and:

$$n=1,2,3,4,5,...\infty$$

Can you show that for every $n$ there are always some zeros $x$:

$$P(x)=0$$

with real part:

$$\Re(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$
?

Mathematica:

```
(*start*)
Clear[x];
Do[Print[{n, 
   Reduce[-x + Conjugate[x]*Sum[x^k, {k, 1, n}] + x^(n + 1) == 0, 
    x]}], {n, 1, 15}]
(*end*)
```

Comment: Using $\sum_{k=1}^n x^k =\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1},$ you get $$P(x)=x(x^{n}-1)\left(1+\frac{x^*}{x-1}\right)$$  

But if $\operatorname{Re} x=1/2,$ then $x+x^*=1$ or $x^*=1-x=-(x-1)$ or $\frac{x^*}{x-1}+1=0.$

Comment: So **all** complex numbers with real part $\frac{1}{2}$ are roots, not just some.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews proved that every number with real part 1/2 is root of this "almost polynomial", so this "almost polynomial" has infinitely many roots. Cool.

Comment: Yes that is how I should have said it. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu It is, of course, obvious that this is possible once you consider the simple cases, $x+x^*-a$ or $xx^*-b$ where $a$ can be any real number and $b$ can be any positive real.